# REST HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, web-services, rest, httpurlconnection

I am working on a REST Client experimenting with the tinkerpop database using using `HttpURLConnection`.

I am trying to send over a `'GET - CONNECT'`. Now I understand (from some net research) that if I use `doOutput(true)` the 'client' will a 'POST' even if I `setRequestMethod` `'GET'` as POST is the default (well ok?) however when I comment out the the `doOutput(true)` I get this error:

```
java.net.ProtocolException: cannot write to a URLConnection if doOutput=false - call setDoOutput(true)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:995)
at RestContent.handleGetConnect(RestContent.java:88)

at RestClient.main(RestClient.java:42)`
```

Here is the communication code snip I have tried various option with `setUseDoOutPut()`.

```
//connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setUseCaches (false);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);

// set GET method 
try {
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
} catch (ProtocolException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
    connection.disconnect();
}
```

Exception at `connection.setRequestMethod("GET")` in the other case. Any hints?

Comment: try `conn.setDoOutput(false);`

Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341602/httpurlconnection-get-request-getting-400-bad-request

Comment: What do you want to send? Is `GET - CONNECT` the body you want to send?

Comment: Why are you writing a body to a GET request? What is wrong with using POST?

Answer (score 2):

Following code works fine: URL is a Rest URL with supported GET operation.

```
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    //connection.setDoOutput(true);
    InputStream content = (InputStream) connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
    String line;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```