# Suffix "-bis" "-ter" in Bulma? What do they mean?

Tags: bulma

I am quite new to front-end development have a maybe dump question. Working with bulma I often come across the suffixes -bis and -ter for colors or color schemes. So, there is

```
$scheme-main-bis
$scheme-main-ter
$scheme-invert
$scheme-invert-bis
$scheme-invert-ter
```

What are they?
It is a bit hard to google? I could not find anything about it.

Thanks

Comment: googling "bis suffix" immediately gets an answer.

Comment: Thanks, but what is black and black-bis then? Just 2 different blacks or is there more to it?

(I get nothing when googling "bis suffix")

Comment: "black" and "a second black"  :-)    Mostly I associate such suffixes with published specifications: suppose there's a telecoms standard V.32, then an update might be V.32 bis.

Comment: I happened to use DuckDuckGo for my search, not Google, maybe that makes a difference.

Comment: @user16632363 its almost two years later and the only useful answer on google is the link to this page where you initially answered in a snarky way. Bulma's use of bis and ter feel really weak here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9105667/1194870

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"second" and "third", respectively.

I would guess that these are just variations on different colour schemes: the main scheme, the other main scheme, and the other other main scheme. ;-)