# REST API Framework. Recommended behavior for invalid querystring parameter

Tags: api, rest, error-handling, query-string

I am implementing a REST API Framework, and I wonder what the recommendedbehavior is, when a client submits an invalid querystring parameter.

I will illustrate what I mean with a specific example:
Say, I have an API handler on the /api/contacts/ endpoint, and the handler provides a querystring filter named `id`, which enables clients to select certain contacts with the provided IDs.

So, a GET or DELETE request could be `/api/contacts/?id=2&id=4&id=lalalala`.

Clearly, there is no such thing as a Contact with `id=lalalala`. In this case, what should the server behave like?

- Ignore the invalid Contact with `id=lalalala`, and only filter the contacts on the valid ids, 2 and 4.
- Respond with an error code that indicates this error. If yes, which error code should be provided?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: To clarify; The main focus of the framework I develop, is having a predictable behavior and hence response codes. For this reason, I want the clients consuming an API built on this framework, to expect the least possible surprises. 
So, the question basically is: Should the API return an error in this case(and if yes, which)? Or ignore invalid filter entries, and only filter on the correct querystring parameters?

Answer (score 16):

Since this is a REST call, we are talking about resources. And whenever we have a wrong filter, we should return a proper error code.

In this case i would go for `400 - bad request` as the resource was found and correctly mapped (`/api/contacts`), but there was a problem with the `query string` part. Therefore a `400` and not a `404`.

Would return a `404` if someone requested `/api/contacts-all` or some non-existant resource.

**EDIT based on comments below**

Agree to your comment. Ideally a `400` is a problem with the request. Going by that, you could use a `422 Unprocessable Entity`. Please look at the stackoverflow link below and it talks about the same thing.

I would guess that developers around the world would be more comfortable seeing a `400` than `422` for such logical errors due to the fact that bigger companies are using `400` and not `422`.

References: 
[Http status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) and 
[400 for logical error vs malformed request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781187/http-400-bad-request-for-logical-error-not-malformed-request-syntax)

Comment: Ravi, thanks for the response. I agree that a 400 error makes a lot of sense. The only thing that stops me from doing so, is that I return 400 error when invalid data are included in the request body (for example in PUT/POST requests), and it seems a bit counter-intuitive, yet reasonable, giving the same response in this case.

Comment: Ravi, thanks. Very complete and clear response. 422 Error seems to be the most correct response, since the request is semantically incorrect. I will study it more thoroughly and get back to you soon.

Comment: 422 is unprocessable entity, but the problem here is a query parameter which is not part of the entity.  I think 404 is best.

Answer (score 10):

Following the letter of the law, the response should be a 404 Not found.  However, nobody is going to get too upset with you if you prefer to return 400 - bad request.

I would definitely return a 4XX status code though.  You want the client to know that they made an error.

Comment: Darrel, thanks for the response. I would disagree with you though that the response should be a 404 error, since the API endpoint is correct, and maps on a valid resource (eg. /api/contacts/). A 400 error would make more sense I suppose :)

Comment: Darrel, you definitely have a point here. As you initially said though, even though following the letter of the law the response could have been a 404 Error, I am leaning more towards a 400 Error.