# How to Check if request.GET.get() redirects to the previous page instead of 404?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm new to django and this is giving me a problem. I'm trying to get a simple GET variable. 
**mysite/search/?q=&start=10&end=20&language=Python**
it works..

My view is:

```
def search(request, invalid_subscribe_to_alert_form=None):
    ...
    start = int(request.GET.get('start', 1)) 
    end = int(request.GET.get('end', 10))
```

and then I request this

**mysite/search/?q=&start=aword&end=20&language=Python**

How do I redirect to the same page in after catching the value error?such that request is gone back to 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Django session framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/sessions/). In the previous correct views, you have to store the value of the last correct page visited:

```
def search(request, invalid_subscribe_to_alert_form=None):
   # ...
   request.session['last-correct-path'] = request.path
```

Then later in the failing view:

```
def search(request, invalid_subscribe_to_alert_form=None):
       # ...
       except ValueError:
           return HttpResponseRedirect(request.session['last-correct-path'])
```

Anyhow if I were you I'd better return 404 or display some error message instead of just redirecting to the last correct page.

Comment: Well I am new to django and it will be helpful if you can tell how can i redirect to a 404 page.

Comment: Google is your friend. But anyhow https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#the-http404-exception

Answer (score 0):

Magic is worse than predictability.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888601/rest-api-framework-recommended-behavior-for-invalid-querystring-parameter) SO has multiple answers pointing towards 40X being the right status code to return when users muck up the parameters in an URL.

Also: Django has [pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/) support (search plugins and REST frameworks often do this for you too, [DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) for example).