# test api controller that returns json response

Tags: json, rest, symfony, phpunit, guzzle

In order to test an API controller in a Symfony2 project  that returns json response, I tried to generate a route of the action like here:

```
$client->getContainer()->get('router')->generate('/api/register/emailverification/', array('email' => 'email@gmail.com'), true)
$response= $client->getResponse();
$this->assertEquals(200, $response);`
```

But the response returns null. I don't know if have to do a specific test for this type of response like using guzzle...

Comment: In tests you should not "generate" routes, they must be hardcoded.

Comment: I tried this : $client   = static::createClient();
$crawler  = $client->request('GET', '/api/register/emailverification/',
                             array('email' => 'email@gmail.com'));
$response = $client->getResponse();

$this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode()); it returns 404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In tests one shouldn't "generate" routes paths, they must be hard-coded:

```
$client = $this->createClient();
$client->request('GET', '/api/register/emailverification/email@gmail.com');
$this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isOk());
```

But if you want to test json, you can do:

```
$this->assertJson($client->getResponse()->getContent());
```

You can find additional PHPunit helpers in the [rest extra bundle](https://github.com/willdurand/BazingaRestExtraBundle/blob/master/Test/WebTestCase.php).

Comment: please how can i add a host to this request because it returns 404 (my host is 127.0.0.1:8000)

Comment: But does your code working in your browser? That's the 1st step.

Comment: copy/past your controller, if 404 it's `/api/register/emailverification/` is not correct.

Comment: 127.0.0.1:8000/api/register/emailverification/email@gmail.com it works like this in browser

Comment: So it's not the same, the email is not a get parameter but part of the route. Answer updated.

Comment: still same issue I think i have to add a host

Comment: How is constructed `$client`? copy/past all the code in the question.

Comment: Try with: $client = $this->createClient() instead.

Comment: just one  more question , when I put a wrong email just for testing ,the assert return fail

Comment: Its depends on how is implemented your controller. If the email is not valid a good practice for a web service is to return a response code 422, check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781187/http-400-bad-request-for-logical-error-not-malformed-request-syntax

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should try:

```
$controllerResponse = $client->getContainer()->get('router')->generate('_validation_email', array('email' => 'email@gmail.com'), true)
$response= $controllerResponse->getResponse();
$this->assertEquals(200, $response);
```

Comment: still the same issue